# how to compile dlib and its examples in debug mode (in ubuntu)?

Tags: c++, debugging, dlib

I'm trying to use ddd (a kind of graphic debugger, using gdb inside) to analyze the dlib , a c++ machine learning library running the dnn_face_recognition_ex example program.
Under the example directory, I did

```
#   mkdir build
#   cd build
#   cmake ..
#   cmake --build . --config Debug
```

but when I run `ddd --args dnn_face_recoginition ../faces/bald_guys.jpg`
I see `no debugging symbols found` message from the ddd.
What should I do? I'm doing it on a ubuntu 16.04 machine.
(But the example program runs ok without debugging.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found http://devdoc.net/c/dlib-19.7/compile.html and tried (under examples/build)

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -g -I../.. ../../dlib/all/source.cpp -lpthread -lX11 ../dnn_face_recognition_ex.cpp -o dnn_face_recognition_ex
```

and now I can run it in debug mode by

```
ddd --args dnn_face_recognition_ex ../faces/bald_guys.jpg
```